# random an infinite generated grid of pictures

Tags: html, css, grid

I have some trouble with this web app I'm making, I need to make an infinite and random grid, but I don't know how to make it random, in that way that either its 2 imgs in a row or 1 big one, I have some pictures of the designer image description here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS6Ru.png)

Answer (score 0):

Css can'not use random, But JS can use random.

this codesanbox [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-fire-r5u6xe?file=/src/App.js)